# How to proof that the union of two semi decidable languages ist semi decidable.

Tags: formal-languages, decision-problems

I am currently studying for my exam in theoretical CS.
In my lecture notes it says:

```
L1 ∪ L2 is semi decidable if L1 and L2 are semi decidable languages.
```

I want to proof the statement above for practice purposes.
At this point, however, I am fairly clueless. Which technique could I use to proof that statement (maybe reduction?, or construct a Turing machine?).
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: You have two machines that list the elements from $L_1$ and $L_2$ respectively. How can you list the element of $L_1 \cup L_2$ to make sure that all elements appear in the list?